# Sleep loop in groovy for hour

Tags: groovy, sleep

hey getting used to groovy and i wanted to have a loop such as a do while loop in my groovy script which is ran every hour or 2 for until a certain condition inside the loop is met (variable = something). So I found the sleep step but was wondering if it would be ok to sleep for such a long time. The sleep function will not mess up right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sleep function will not mess up. But that isn't your biggest problem.

If all your script is doing is sleeping, it would be better to have a scheduler like [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) launch your script. This way is simpler and more resilient, it reduces the opportunities for the script to be accumulating garbage, leaking memory, having its JVM get killed by another process, or otherwise just falling into a bad state from programming errors. Cron is solid and there is less that can go wrong that way. Starting up a JVM is not speedy but if your timeframe is in hours it shouldn't be a problem.

Another possible issue is that the time your script wakes up may drift. The OS scheduler is not obliged to wake your thread up at exactly the elapsed time. Also the time on the server could be changed while the script is running. Using Cron would make the time your script acts more predictable.

On the other hand, with the scheduler, if a process takes longer than the time to the next run, there is the chance that multiple instances of the process can exist concurrently. You might want to have the script create a lock file and remove it once it's done, checking to see if the file exists already to let it know if another instance is still running.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's not `do {} while()` construct in groovy. Secondly it's a better idea to use a scheduler e.g. [QuartzScheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) to run a cron task.